# MySQL SELECT if there is no newer record

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'm trying to pull contracts from MySQL that are expiring soon. Which I did with the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.file, c.user, c.contractno, c.startdate, c.enddate, f.name, f.path 
FROM signedcontracts c 
LEFT JOIN files f ON c.file = f.id 
    WHERE c.enddate < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    AND c.enddate > NOW() 
ORDER BY c.enddate ASC
```

But I can't figure out how to make sure it doesn't return any contracts for users that already have a new contract in `signedcontracts`.

Comment: Please add some data to your question if possible.

Comment: What data would you like?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. PS What does "already have a new contract" mean? Why are you left joining if you don't want all left table rows represented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this query:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.file, c.user, c.contractno, c.startdate, c.enddate, f.name, f.path 
FROM signedcontracts c 
LEFT JOIN files f ON c.file = f.id 
    WHERE c.enddate < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    AND c.enddate > NOW()
    AND c.user NOT IN (SELECT user FROM signedcontracts WHERE enddate > NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)
ORDER BY c.enddate ASC
```

Which checks if the user doesn't have a contract with more than 30 days until `enddate`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just need to check that there is no end date after now + 30 days

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | start_date | end_date   |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 2017-10-01 | 2017-10-31 |
|    1 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-31 |
|    2 | 2017-10-01 | 2017-12-31 |
|    2 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-31 |
|    3 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-31 |
|    4 | 2017-10-01 | 2018-10-31 |
+------+------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select *
    -> from t
    -> where end_date between now()  and now() + interval 30 day
    -> and id not in (select id from t where end_date > now() + interval 30 day);
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | start_date | end_date   |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-31 |
+------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```